# alternative for foreach and use regular for loop

Tags: javascript

This doesnt really work in IE

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.some-class-selector'), function(arg) {

   callSomeFucntion(arg)

});
```

because forEach doesn't work on IE. if I want to do this using for loop, how would I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Are you asking us how to write a `for` loop?

Comment: search [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for "polyfill"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: [`forEach` has been supported since IE9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility).  What version of IE are you using?

Comment: May I suggest you look into transpiling, working around old browser technology is one way to make me puke.!!.   Get into modern ESNext features and use `for of`..

Answer (score 0):

Need to add this for run forEach in IE

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7" />`

Answer (score -1):

What version of IE are you using? The Microsoft docs page for forEach lists the version that  don't support it - mainly IE 6,7 and 8 or quirks mode (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/foreach-method-array-javascript)

You can also use a polyfill if your browser won't support it [MDN `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> forEach() was added to the ECMA-262 standard in the 5th edition; as
>   such it may not be present in other implementations of the standard.
>   You can work around this by inserting the following code at the
>   beginning of your scripts, allowing use of forEach() in
>   implementations that don't natively support it. This algorithm is
>   exactly the one specified in ECMA-262, 5th edition, assuming Object
>   and TypeError have their original values and that callback.call()
>   evaluates to the original value of Function.prototype.call().
>
> ```
> // Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.18
> // Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.18
> if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
>
> Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback/*, thisArg*/) {
>
> var T, k;
>
> if (this == null) {
>   throw new TypeError('this is null or not defined');
> }
>
> // 1. Let O be the result of calling toObject() passing the
> // |this| value as the argument.
> var O = Object(this);
>
> // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get() internal
> // method of O with the argument "length".
> // 3. Let len be toUint32(lenValue).
> var len = O.length >>> 0;
>
> // 4. If isCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception. 
> // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
> if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
>   throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
> }
>
> // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let
> // T be undefined.
> if (arguments.length > 1) {
>   T = arguments[1];
> }
>
> // 6. Let k be 0.
> k = 0;
>
> // 7. Repeat while k < len.
> while (k < len) {
>
>   var kValue;
>
>   // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
>   //    This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator.
>   // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty
>   //    internal method of O with argument Pk.
>   //    This step can be combined with c.
>   // c. If kPresent is true, then
>   if (k in O) {
>
>     // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal
>     // method of O with argument Pk.
>     kValue = O[k];
>
>     // ii. Call the Call internal method of callback with T as
>     // the this value and argument list containing kValue, k, and O.
>     callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);
>   }
>   // d. Increase k by 1.
>   k++;
> }
> // 8. return undefined.
> };
> }
> ```